# If $X = g(Y) + Z$, with $Y,Z$ independent continu0us RVs, what is the conditional density $f_{X \mid Y=y}(x)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ be a probability space. Suppose that $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R^n$ and $Z:\Omega \to \mathbb R^m$ are independent, continuous random vectors with probability density functions $f_Y$ and $f_Z$, respectively, and that
$$
X = g(Y) + Z
$$
for some function $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. It seems that it should be obvious that
$$
f_{X \mid Y = y}(x) = f_Z(x - g(y)),
$$
but how do we prove this fact?

(Feel free to take $m = n = 1$ for simplicity, if that is helpful. We can assume $g$ satisfies whatever mild regularity condition is convenient.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of conditional the probability density function, a Jacobian change of variables, and the independence of $Y$ from $Z$.

$$\begin{align}f_{X\mid Y=y}(x) & =\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}\\[1ex] & = \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial [ x-g(y),y]}{\partial [x,y]}\end{Vmatrix}\cdot\dfrac{f_{Z,Y}(x-g(y),y)}{f_Y(y)}\\[1ex] &= \dfrac{\lvert 1\rvert\cdot f_Z(x-g(y))\cdot f_Y(y)}{f_Y(y)}\\[1ex] &= f_{Z}(x-g(y)) \end{align}$$That is all.